# How to flatten a list of dictionaries with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection of `Employee` objects which have a `Skills` property. It's a dictionary where the key is particular **skill** and value is **skill level** in some abstract unit.

Example:

```
{ "C#", 5 },
{ "Java", 2 },
{ "XML", 5 }
```

Example code

```cs
public class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, int> Skills { get; set; }
}
public class EmployeeAssessment
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<Employee> employees;    

    public EmployeeAssessment(IEnumerable<Employee> employees)
    {
        this.employees = employees;
    }

    public List<Employee> GetEmployeesWithMinimalSkillLevel(string skillName)
    {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

`GetEmployeesWithMinimalSkillLevel` fetches a list of employees who have a minimum skill level for a given skill, for example, "Java".

I wrote an efficient solution using **loops** but it doesn't seem elegant to me and I want to rewrite it using LINQ, preferably in a single query.

I always end up with 2 or more LINQ statements and I wonder if it's actually possible to do in single statement. Thanks.

Comment: Follow the [LINQ LINK](https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/8-tips-writing-best-linq-to-entities-queries.aspx). Does this link help your purpose?

Comment: Please show us your attempts at the LINQ statements.

Comment: Your method doesn't have a means of specifying the required skill level. Also, I would expect to see only one loop as getting the skill from the employee would be using a dictionary lookup by key. That's about as efficient as you can get it, and it would be easier to read than LINQ.

Comment: I think you need some sample input and output to make it clear. Otherwise we are trying to read your mind and guessing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll start with example reproduction.

So, we have `Employee` model:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } // <-- Added just for readability
    public Dictionary<string, int> Skills { get; set; }

    // Simple string representation
    public override string ToString() => 
        $"{Name} (ID #{ID}) skills:\t {string.Join(" | ", Skills.Select(skill => $"{skill.Key}: {skill.Value}"))}";
}
```

Let's create a List of 10 Employees with some skills and random skill levels:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var random = new Random();
    var employees = new List<Employee>();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        employees.Add(new Employee
        {
            ID = i,
            // Simple name
            Name = "Employee #" + i,
            Skills = new Dictionary<string, int>()
            { 
                // 0-10 is random skill level
                { "C#", random.Next(0, 10) },
                { "Java", random.Next(0, 10) },
                { "XML", random.Next(0, 10) },
                { "HTML", random.Next(0, 10) } // :D
            }
        });
    }

    Console.WriteLine("All employees:");
    employees.ForEach(employee => Console.WriteLine(employee.ToString()));
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

That will give us this kind of output:
[image]

**ANSWER PART.**

If we want to filter employee by some *Minimal Skill Level* - we should define which level could be minimal. For example, let's take **3** (of 10). Than, to filter employees by skill level, we could use LINQ in `EmployeeAssessment.GetEmployeesWithMinimalSkillLevel` method:

```
public class EmployeeAssessment
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<Employee> employees;

    public EmployeeAssessment(IEnumerable<Employee> employees)
    {
        this.employees = employees;
    }

    public List<Employee> GetEmployeesWithMinimalSkillLevel(string skillName, int minimalSkillLevel = 3)
    {
        return (from employee in employees
                from skill in employee.Skills
                where skill.Key == skillName && skill.Value <= minimalSkillLevel
                select employee).ToList();
    }       
}
```

Or it could be maked in 1 line using `.Where` and `.Any` extension methods:

```
public List<Employee> GetEmployeesWithMinimalSkillLevel(string skillName, int minimalSkillLevel = 3)
{
    return employees.Where(employee => employee.Skills.Any(skill => skill.Key == skillName && skill.Value <= minimalSkillLevel)).ToList();
}
```

In both ways we iterating each `Employee` `Skills` dictionary to find `Key`, which equal to skill we provided as `skillName` and check that its `Value` is less than or equal to our defined `minimalSkillLevel`. Iteration in original way looks like `foreach` loops:

```
public List<Employee> GetEmployeesWithMinimalSkillLevel(string skillName, int minimalSkillLevel = 3)
{
    List<Employee> employeesWithMinimalSkillLevel = new List<Employee>();

    foreach (Employee employee in employees)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> skill in employee.Skills)
        {
            if (skill.Key == skillName && skill.Value <= minimalSkillLevel)
            {
                employeesWithMinimalSkillLevel.Add(employee);
            }
        }
    }

    return employeesWithMinimalSkillLevel;
}
```

And when we call one of this methods (or both), we will get filtered List of Employees, whos defined skill (*"C#"* in example) is less than or equal 3:
[image]

Comment: Looks impressive.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code in you `EmployeeAssessment.cs`

```
public List<Employee> GetEmployeesWithMinimalSkillLevel(string skillName)
{
   return employees.Where(x => x.Skills[skillName] == employees.Min(x => x.Skills[skillName]));
}
```

Hope this is helpful, You can optimize it further if you want to.